# Lightning Web Component Push Failed

Tags: lightning-web-components, push

i import the method that i have to use in JavaScript file like this

`import getRoles from '@salesforce/apex/LeaveSettingsController.getRoles';`

`@wire(getRoles)`
 `rolesList;`

when i'm trying to push the code to my scratch org i got an error like this 
Unable to find Apex action class referenced as 'LeaveSettingsController'

I create an apex class in my DevHub org

```
public with sharing class LeaveSettingsController {

    public LeaveSettingsController(){

    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<UserRole> getRoles(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole];
    }
}
```

I have a DevHub org and only one scratch org and i use this command to push the code to the scratch org using the VS Code:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

Comment: Do you have apex class named LeaveSettingsController? Which command are you trying to deploy your code?

Comment: Have you opened the developer console on the scratch org and hit Ctrl+shift+O and searched for your class?  Although the output in the terminal when you hit sfdx force:source:push should have listed the class as deployed

Comment: @akarnid i searched for my class and it not exist in my scratch org can you tell me why this it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create an apex class using below command from command palette,

```
sfdx: create apex class
```

You need to enter your class name, then just press enter to select default directory for apex classes.

A class will be created in your project in a folder like `...\default\classes`.

Just paste all your code over there.

Then you can push to scratch org, which will create an apex class in your scratch org, and you won't get any error.

**Update - An alternate way:** If scratch org is open in the browser, you can also create apex class from there by going to setup -> Apex Classes.

Comment: Thank you very much i did exactly what you say before and now it works!

Comment: @sallyyamak if this answers your question mark the answer as correct and it will help future people trying to find answers to similar questions

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appeared because during on deploy I forgot to include Apex Classes

I used a command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m LightningComponentBundle
```

while I should have used a command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass,LightningComponentBundle
```

This helps in the case when the source code is deployed from Version Control System into Developer Edition organization or to the scratch org as well.

However, in case of scratch org, instead of command

```
sfdx force:source:push -m LightningComponentBundle
```

another command should be used

```
sfdx force:source:push -m ApexClass,LightningComponentBundle
```